# Calculating JMP instruction's address

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address

I am trying to hook a function by replacing its beginning with a JMP instruction which should lead to my function. But the problem is that I don't know how to calculate the JMP offset to target the address of my function. Well, I know how to do it if you jump forward in memory (Destination addr - Current addr), but I haven't got any ideas how to determine it when you jump back in memory.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 8):

Just use negative offset to jump backwards.

And remember to account for the size of the `JMP` instruction.  The offset is relative to the end of the `JMP` instruction and not the beginning.  If the current address is where you are about to write the `JMP` then you need an offet of 5+dest-current since the size of the `JMP` instruction plus the offset if 5 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

This is basic math that you should be able to figure out. :)

If a JMP forward is `Destination - Origin`, then a `JMP` backward would be `Origin - Destination`

Think about it in plain numbers: If you want to `JMP` forward from 100 to 110, your `JMP` would be `110 - 100 = 10`. If you want to `JMP` the same amount backward, it would be `100 - 110 = -10`.

Comment: No-no, I know how to jump forward of course. The problem is, I am not sure how to calculate and represent it in HEX then. For example, if I want to jump from address 1000 to 2000, it will be "E9 3E8", but what will it be if I want to jump from address 2000 to 1000? Something horrible like "E9 FFFFFFFFFFFFFC18"?

Comment: Hex is no different. Change my example from `100` to `0x100` and `110` to `0x110`, and the math is the same.

Comment: user972948: it's nothing horrible, it's just the two's complement of the negative offset you want.

Answer (score 1):

relative jumps are signed, that is, they have positive and negative displacement using the sign bit. absolute jumps are absolute so it doesn't matter. see volumes 2A & 2B of the intel instruction guide.

Answer (score -2):

hello i suggest you use the 'call' statement. The 'call' statement will take care of putting the return pointer on the stack.

the formula to calculate the jump you need to do is: ToAddress - FromAddress - 5

-5 this is because it is the space that the 'call' + offset instruction occupies in memory

pointers in memory are written inversely. if you want to point to memory 0x857830, in memory this value is written 307885

instructions opcode
jmp = 0xE9
call = 0xE8

Comment: The question is not about using `call` or `jmp` so that's misplaced. And little-endian dword encoding, while relevant, is not well represented by two multi-digit strings. You should instead write eg `30 78 85 00` in order to list the bytes for a little endian dword `857830h`. You forgot to include the trailing zero (from the highest byte of the dword), too.

Answer (score -6):

Be sneaky

Make a dummy call to a location above your function

```
 call location1


 .location1
 call location2
 .location2
 pop ax
 ret
 .yourfunction
```

You now have the address of location2 in ax

add 3 to ax and you have the memory address of your function