# Calculating JMP instruction's address (x86-64)

Tags: assembly, c++-cli, x86-64, memory-address

The same question as here: [Calculating JMP instruction's address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609549/calculating-jmp-instructions-address)

How to use this code on 64-bit machine? What should be changed?

```
// TODO: 64-bit.
void Manager::InjectCode( PBYTE & p, int k, int n ) {

    * p++ = 0xB8; // mov eax, imm32
    p[0] = k;
    p += sizeof( int );

    * p++ = 0xA3; // mov [assemblyId], eax
    ( int * & ) p[0] = & assemblyId; 
    p += sizeof( int * ); 

    * p++ = 0xB8; // mov eax, imm32
    p[0] = n;
    p += sizeof( int );

    * p++ = 0xA3; // mov [functionId], eax
    ( int * & ) p[0] = & functionId; 
    p += sizeof( int * );         

    // jmp to CallbackFunction. 
    * p++ = 0xE9;
    ( UINT & ) p[0] = ( PBYTE ) ::CallbackFunction - 4 - p;
    p += sizeof( PBYTE );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final `p += sizeof(PBYTE)` needs to be changed to `p += 4` because the offset is still 32 bit, even though pointers are 64 bit. You might also need a cast to `int`. This would still work in 32 bit mode as well, so you don't have to create a separate version just for this. You have to make sure the jump target is within 32 bit range though. Otherwise, you can use an indirect jump:

```
mov rax, CallbackFunction ; 48 b8 xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx
jmp rax                   ; ff e0
```