# Calculating JMP instruction's address for trampoline hook

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86, memory-address

I am trying to calculate the relative address offset from one instruction to another.

I understand the basic calculation, and why I have to -5 (to cater for size of jmp and instruction size) ([Calculating JMP instruction's address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609549/calculating-jmp-instructions-address))

The question is, what if I want to jump not to start of a code but some specific instructions after it?

For example:

[original function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSL67.png)

I want to JMP to the highlighted instruction OPENGL32.dll+48195, while I only have the start address of OPENGL32.wglSwapBu.

From my code, I understand I can do

```
uintptr_t gatewayRelativeAddr = src - gateway - 5;
```

where src is the address of OPENGL32.wglSwapBu and gateway is the start address of my code.

```
// len is 5

BYTE* gateway = (BYTE*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, len+5, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, 
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
memcpy_s(gateway, len, src, len);

// Jump back to original function, but at the highlighted instruction
uintptr_t gatewayRelativeAddr = src - gateway - 5;

// add the jmp opcode to end of gateway

*(gateway + len) = 0xE9;

*(uintptr_t*)(gateway + len + 1) = gatewayRelativeAddr;
```

I understand thus far what the code does:
calculate the relative address/bytes from the start address of `gateway` to start address of `src`(original function). I also -5 to cater for the size of the jump.

However, when I viewed it in memory, it ended up at where I want. But no where in the code I specified it to jmp to the highlighted instruction.

Comment: Obviously you can calculate the jump displacement to any address you want.  If you know the place you want is 11 bytes into the `src` function, use `src+11` instead of `src`, and nothing else changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works because `len` equals exactly the number of bytes of instructions (5) that precede the desired one, which I presume was the whole point (you want to copy the instructions that will be jumped over, and maybe modify them later on?).

The jump instruction starts at `gateway+len`, and so EIP at the jump will be `gateway+len+5`.  On the other hand, the address you want to jump to is `src+len`.  So the relative address is `(src+len)-(gateway+len+5)`, and `len` cancels out, so your formula is correct.

If you want to jump to an instruction that's not the next one after the ones you copied, you'll need to work out its offset from `src` by disassembly (call it `ofs`), and then set `gatewayRelativeAddr` to `(src+ofs)-(gateway+len+5)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally understand why it worked that way. Is it correct if instead of thinking of EIP method you mention it, I  think of it as as : (gateway+len+5), +5 because that's the size of the JMP+addr instruction, hence that will give us the correct "number of bytes" away from end of JMP instruction to the place we want to jump to, (gateway+len)?

Comment: @menagos652: Sure, I think that's the same.  Since the jump instruction at `gateway+len` is 5 bytes long, the following instruction is at `gateway+len+5`.  That's the value EIP will have as the jump instruction is executed, and so that's what you must subtract from the desired jump destination.